# Folder-by-feature and decorator design pattern

Tags: java, decorator, directory-structure

Folder-by-feature and decorator pattern

If I have a `Parser` that has an associated `Stream`, when I progress through the `Tokens`, I am mutating the state of the object as the `Stream` is moving forward. I want to add app-specific functionality to this parser to maintain the principle of single responsibility, so I thought the Decorator design pattern was an appropriate choice. I now wrap the `Parser` in a `ParserDecorator(Parser)` and add specific functions, such as `readPerson()` or `readItem()` that maps the data to an `Object` and returns that `Object`.

First, I considered making a static function within `Person` that takes the `Parser` as an argument; however, the function progresses the stream and I decided that would not be thread safe in all cases. As the `ParserDecorator`, though, return objects of different types, there is no way to keep it logically grouped with `Person` only. So if I change the Person class later, I have to remember to change how it is read by the `ParserDecorator`, which is located in a different part of the program and a new developer on the project may not check that location. Typically I deploy folder-by-feature so all the changes that would need to be made are located together, but it does not work in this case.

Is there a better solution to this case, working with a purely object-oriented approach? Right now I have a separate feature-folder called util that has this class.

EDIT:
Example code:

```
public class JsonParserDecorator {
    private final JsonParser jsonParser;

    public JsonParserDecorator(JsonParser jsonParser) {
        this.jsonParser = jsonParser;
    }

    public Item readItem() throws IOException {
        Item item = new Item();

        if (jsonParser.currentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            throw new IOException("JSON object expected");
        }

        while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            String fieldName = jsonParser.currentName();
            jsonParser.nextToken();

            switch (fieldName) {
                case "itemId":
                    item.setId(jsonParser.getLongValue());
                    break;
                case "description":
                    item.setDescription(jsonParser.getText());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what kind of objects the parser decorator is returning?

Comment: To me it sounds like Decorator is not the pattern you are looking for. A decorator would be useful, if every parsed token requires the same (albeit modular) set of processing steps. But in your case, there is probably a difference in processing `Person`vs `Item` tokens. The bridge pattern would allow you to have abstractions for 1) token types and 2) token type specific parsing behaviour.

Comment: I added code with JsonParser for example, and Item as an object to demonstrate how I am attempting to structure the program.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a solution after thinking about it overnight. I created a new class called `ItemJson` and added `read(JsonParser jsonParser)` and `write(JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, Item item)` methods. This keeps all of the similar classes/features together and handles the reformatting of data in a single, separate class.